# libgdx robovm crashes on detatch thread with non native frames on the call stack

Tags: java, ios, facebook, libgdx, robovm

I have been off and on trying to fix this crash for weeks now, but I have not yet found the problem. When I run the following function "GetAchievementsInformation()" in my Libgdx game the app crashes with a "cannot detach thread when there are non native frames on the call stack"

Am I doing something wrong here? Most of my other facebook requests run just fine (I have a second one that gives the same error)

```
public FBRequest GetAchievementsRequest() 
{
    return new FBRequest(FBSession.getActiveSession(),"/"+ APP_ID + "/achievements", null,"GET");
}

FBRequestHandler GetAchievementsRequestHandler()
{
    return new FBRequestHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void invoke(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject data, NSError error) 
        {
            if (error != null) 
            {
                Gdx.app.log("error", error.toString());
                logout();
                return;
            }

            JSONArray achievements_data;
            try {
                achievements_data = NSObjectToJSONObject(data).getJSONArray("data");

                for(int i=0;i<achievements_data.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject achievement_data = achievements_data.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject pointdata =  achievement_data.getJSONObject("data");
                    String points_data = pointdata.get("points").toString();
                    int score = Integer.parseInt(points_data);
                    String url = achievement_data.get("url").toString();
                    JSONArray list = achievement_data.getJSONArray("image");
                    String image_url = list.getJSONObject(0).get("url").toString();
                    achievementManager.AddInformationToAchievement(url, score,image_url);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Gdx.app.log("request", "get achieved achievements");
            GetAchievedAchievementsRequest().start(GetAchievedAchievementRequestHandler());
        }

    };
}

public FBRequest GetAchievedAchievementsRequest() 
{
    return new FBRequest(FBSession.getActiveSession(),"/me/achievements", null, "GET");
}

FBRequestHandler GetAchievedAchievementRequestHandler()
{
    return new FBRequestHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void invoke(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject data,NSError error) 
        {
            if (error != null) 
            {
                Gdx.app.log("error", error.toString());
                logout();
                return;
            }
            JSONArray achievements_data;
            try 
            {
                achievements_data = NSObjectToJSONObject(data).getJSONArray("data");                
                for(int i=0;i<achievements_data.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject achievement_data =  achievements_data.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONObject achievement_sub_data = achievement_data.getJSONObject("achievement");
                    String url = achievement_sub_data.get("url").toString();
                    achievementManager.UnlockedAchievement(url);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            achievementManager.SetupAchievementsFinished();     //finished loading after this
        }
    };
}

public void GetAchievementInformation()
{
    Gdx.app.log("request", "Getting achievement information");
    GetAchievementsRequest().start(GetAchievementsRequestHandler());
}

JSONObject NSObjectToJSONObject(NSObject object)
{
    JSONObject json = null;
    String jsonString64 = NSJSONSerialization.createJSONData(object, NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted).toBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
    String jsonString = Base64Coder.decodeString(jsonString64);
    Gdx.app.log("json", "to json:" + jsonString);

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: At what line this error happens? Does it happen every time?

Comment: Since I have a rather slow macbook, i cant run the debugger because it times out before connecting every time. Using debug lines I did manage to find that the problem lies within: GetAchievementsRequest().start(GetAchievementsRequestHandler());
Funny thing is, when i wrote the functions out the problem did not occur at this spot, but at a later request down the line.  I will investigate further and update the question/answer if I find out what was wrong. This might just be random though.

Comment: It was too good to be true. It seems that there is some randomness in the time this error occurs. But however I do it, when I run this request the error happens at a point after finishing the request. If I do not run the request it does not happen. One way or the other I do not do anything with the achievement information before the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a memory leak fixed by adding: connection.dispose();

I'm not sure why this is not an issue with the other requests I do. But here it caused the crash.